# How to select a oracle table from postgresql script?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I need to access Oracle table from PostgreSQL script.

I am trying to create a function in PostgreSQL to access oracle table's as input by select query.

Please provide the process to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out foreign data wrappers: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrapper#oracle_fdw

Comment: see this also http://pgxn.org/dist/oracle_fdw/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#oracle_fdw) - they let you map a remote table in a different system to a local one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Richard. 

Is there any step step process reference for PostgreSQL Database Link to Oracle Database on windows machine?

Comment: Nothing specifically covering exactly that, but there are plenty of examples of fdw setup and windows binaries avaiable on the project page.